# Angular/Typescript, calling next on subscriber in error call back on http error callback

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I've seen a couple similar questions here but nothing seems to address my question, so I apologize if this has already been asked.

I am using Angular 9 (Typescript obviously), wrapping an angular http call in an observable pattern because I want to just have this method return a null to abstract the observable away from the caller.

```
 public createCase = (caseTypeId: string, displayName: string) : Observable<CaseData> => {
    const apiURL = `${environment.baseApi}/case`;
    return new Observable<CaseData>((observable) => {
      this.http
        .post<CaseData>(apiURL, newCase)
        .subscribe(
          caseData => observable.next(caseData),
          error => {
            console.log(error.status);
            observable.next(null);
          },
          () => observable.complete());
    });
}
```

I am calling the above method with the following code in a separate class:

```
public outerCreateCase = async (caseTypeId: string) : Promise<CaseData> => {
    let response = await this._caseApi.createCase(caseTypeId, "TEST").toPromise();    
    ... do stuff based on response ...
    return response;
}
```

There is a bit of logic around this that is removed for the purposes of the question but I think this highlights my point. Basically I just want to have the http call return a null to the promise as the observable pattern becomes cumbersome when my calls are nested several methods deep. The caller to outer call just needs a response object or a null to do it's thing. The problem is that the code after the await in outerCreateCase never gets called when the http call returns an error.  It returns fine when the http call is successful. Anybody have any idea why this is happening?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a `new Observable`. You can just use `catchError` operator.
The code should look like the following.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
......
this.http
  .post<CaseData>(apiURL, newCase)
  .pipe(
    catchError => {
      console.log(error.status);
      return of(null)
    }
  );
```